# Hyperlink click event on extjs 4 grid

Tags: extjs

I am facing an issue in listening to the click event for hyperlink in extjs grid. Actually I have a form whose display field’s value is a hyperlink. On click of this hyperlink, I show a window pop-up which a grid(single column) and has multiple values,one  value for each row(which are again hyperlinks). On click of this I show a form. On  the click of hyperlink on grid column, I have this listener:

```
           cellclick:function(){
           Ext.getBody().on(‘click’,function(event,target){
           MyModel.getProxy().url =  ‘…’;
           MyModel.load({
           scope:this;
           callback:function(){
                                }
            });

            },null,{
            delegate:’.className’
            });

           }
```

On click of the hyperlink on grid row, there is a call to the rest service. When I click on any value for the first time, it works fine. When I click on any other value, there are two service calls, one for the value that is clicked and one for the previously clicked value and this goes on increasing with the increase in the number of clicks.How can I avoid this?Is there any other way to  listen to the hyperlink click event?Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks….

Comment: Why are you adding a delegated listener to the body on each cell click? Just listen to the body once when your grid starts up. Remove it when the grid is destroyed.

Comment: Can you help me with this?What changes will I have to make to the above code?thanks